# Return lambda with capture from a function in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

The [standard 5.1.2 6](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) says that there is a conversion function from a lambda expression without capture to the corresponding function pointer type. What about lambdas with capture? The following code compiles without warnings. Does this lead to undefined behavior?

```
std::function<void()> makeFucntion(int& parameter)
{
    return [&parameter]() // convert the lambda to std::function
    {
        cout << parameter;
    };
}

int var = 4;
auto foo = makeFucntion(var);
foo();
```

And if there is undefined behavior, is there another way to return a lambda expression with a capture from a function in c++11?

Comment: The code here does not use or need function pointers.  You may construct a `std::function` from a lambda.

Comment: The **undefined behavior** is not due to 5.1.2 6.  If the capture-by-reference lambda is used after the referenced object is destroyed, then it would be **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::function<void()>` is not a function pointer. `std::function<void()>` can store more than just function pointers.

If you'd try to return a function pointer `void(*)()` then the code would fail to compile, because lambdas with capture do not have a conversion to function pointer.

As `parameter` is passed and capture by referene and `var` is still in scope while you call `foo()` the code is fine.